# Android & Mockito. Is there any way to access private viewModel class member to verify that method called?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

1. I have a Fragment.
2. Fragment has a private viewModel class member.
3. Fragment contains SwipeRefreshLayout.
4. I need to write test like "verify that when SwipeRefreshLayout swiped viewModel.refreshForecast() method was called".

Problem: I don't don't know how I can get access to private viewModel class here.

Example what I want to write:

```
    @Test
    fun `test swipe refresh toggle forecast update`() {
        scenario.onFragment {

            onView(withId(R.id.suggestionSwipeRefresh)).perform(ViewActions.swipeDown())

            verify(viewModel).refreshForecast() // How to get viewModelHere ???
        }
    }
```

My fragment class

````
class SuggestionFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
    private lateinit var viewModel: SuggestionViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        AwesomeApplication.appComponent.inject(this)

        suggestionSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            viewModel.refreshForecast()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(SuggestionViewModel::class.java)

    }
    ```
````

Comment: why is your viewmodel private ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody, it's normal when viewModel is private so I didn't see any problem in it.

I understand what you mean and YES - I can make class members/methods public and available for test but this code will "smell".

Comment: i dont see the harm in making this public, it's not as if making this public will make anything worse as nothing can use an instance of this VM anyway, it's not like someone can make an instance of a fragment and then start using the VM, i don't see the harm in making it public :)